# Using c#, how to extract propertybags created in vb6 sent via MSMQ

Tags: c#, vb6, msmq, propertybag

I have a legacy application written in vb6 which produces MSMQ messages. The body of these MSMQ messages contain `PropertyBags`.

My question is: how can I, using C#, retrieve the content of these messages created in vb6, containing propertybags and transmitted via MSMQ?

Should I be using `ActiveXMessageFormatter`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You could create a simple VB6 component to read the messages and return the contents to C# via COM?

Comment: That, or reverse-engineer the byte array format and open source the implementation :-))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a propertybag or complex object send from VB6 through MSMQ in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404013/how-to-extract-a-propertybag-or-complex-object-send-from-vb6-through-msmq-in-c-s)